# Display template not displaying with UIHint attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying out display templates in MVC 4.

I create my displaytemplate in Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\MyDate.cshtml

```
@model System.DateTime

<span>  
    @Model.ToString("dd / MM / yyyy")
</span>
```

I try to use it in my view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.TestDate, "MyDate")
```

So far so good. Now I want to do the same thing with the UIHint attribute. So I add another field in my model:

```
[UIHint("MyDate")]
public DateTime Yesterday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

So I figure I can simply add it to my view like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Yesterday)
```

But oh no, my markup from my displaytemplate MyDate.cshtml is nowhere to be seen... What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Couldn't it be, that you use `field` instead of `property`? Try `public DateTime Yesterday { get { return DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);}} `

Comment: Thanks! You're right, it works as a `property`.

Comment: I'm not sure why though, It's fine when it's a `field` as long as i do `@Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Yesterday, "MyDate")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you using `field`, but not `property`.

That's what you should do:

```
public DateTime Yesterday { get { return DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1); } }
```